# Change other options based on dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

What I'd like to do is automatically change other dropdowns based on the answer of one specific select | option dropdown. In this case when the main dropdown changes to "Change" I'd like the other dropdowns to find the "Refused to Answer" options. (http://jsfiddle.net/sNZ5X/)

HTML

```
<h3>Main Select Dropdown
    <select id="master">
        <option>Do Nothing</option>
        <option>Change</option>
    </select>
</h3>
<hr>
<p class="important">Question 1
    <select class="rta">
        <option>Answer 1</option>
        <option>Answer 2</option>
        <option>Refused to Answer</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p class="required">Question 2
    <select class="rta">
        <option>Answer 1</option>
        <option>Answer 2</option>
        <option>Refused to Answer</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

JS

```
$( "#master" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "Refusted to Answer";
    if $(master).selected = "Change"
    $( ".rta" ).change( str );
  })
  .change();
```

Comment: What do you want `.rta` to change to? The value of the dropdown, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[done,  heres the FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sNZ5X/4/)

Basically you needed to test for the value properly, and set the selected value properly. Also your string for "Refused to Answer" was spelled wrong, never would have matched.

```
$('#master').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'Change') {
        $('.rta').val('Refused to Answer');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks. It's been a long day and syntax was not on my side today.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your script (always check your browser console):

1. `master` is not defined. I suppose you meant `$('#master')` instead of `$(master)`.
2. `.selected` is not a valid method.
3. `=` is used for assignment. Use `==` for comparison
4. Invalid `if` statement - use brackets ;)

Here's the working example on [<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/sNZ5X/3/):

```
$( "#master" )
  .change(function () {
      if ($('#master option:selected').val() == "Change")
          // Assuming that last child is always 'Refused to answer'
          $('.rta option:last-child').prop('selected', true);
  })
  .change();
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to review all the drop down children to see if they will be the last answer - if so this will work just nicely! Thanks for the tips, too.